# JS Prototype not running through its full function

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

This is my code, I'm attempting to set up a combo lock for a game that will unlock when the user inputs the correct answer. However, when the user inputs something it will always return "The door is unlocked." What am I missing or doing wrong here?

```
function comboLock(){
  this.comboLock = ["666"];
  this.falseInput = /[^1-5, 7-9]/g;
}
comboLock.prototype.unlock = function(){
  if (this.comboLock != this.falseInput){
    return alert("the door is unlocked");
  }
  else if (this.comboLock === this.falseInput){
    return alert("that is not the correct combonation");
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button-unlock").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.comboLock = "666"){
      return alert("the door is unlocked");
    }
    else if (this.comboLock != "666"){
      return alert("that is not the correct combonation");
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Don't use `!=` to compare input to a regex.  Use a regex string comparison operator like the string function `match()`

Comment: Why are you using a regular expression as input, also you might be misunderstanding prototypes. Can you tell us what you think should be happening?